# Java EE 7 Batch Processor onStop for chunk jobs

Tags: java, batch-processing

I have been reading a bit about the Java EE 7.0 batch processor on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html. As explained there are 2 job types, chunk oriented and task oriented. I am using the chunk oriented approach, but the problem is that I cannot find a way to catch the Stop event when I stop the job. I see that in the task oriented jobs, you can override the onStop method but not in chunk jobs.

Anyone know how to handle the stop event in chunk jobs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot get actively notified during a chunk step.
What you may do: Check the BatchStatus for "STOPPED" or "STOPPING" at certain points within your code and react on it.

For my custom Batchlets (task-oriented steps) I’m using a common parent class that provides the following method:

```
protected boolean isStopped() {
    if (BatchStatus.STOPPED.equals(jobContext.getBatchStatus())
        || BatchStatus.STOPPING.equals(jobContext.getBatchStatus())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This condition check should also work in chunk operations or in inherited classes of AbstractItemReader, AbstractItemWriter and implementations of ItemProcessor.

This is also a good way to handle the stop event gracefully in a batchlet job, as the stop event is executed on a thread other than the thread on which the batchlet process method is running.
With tactically placed stop-checks in task-oriented jobs you may ensure that you’re not running into a performance and/or time consuming action when the jobContext is asking you for a stop.

Comment: Note such an enhancement has been [proposed](https://java.net/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7361)  for the [Batch 1.1 spec update](https://github.com/WASdev/standards.jsr352.batch-spec/wiki).